# What does ${} (dollar sign and curly braces) mean in a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, variables, concatenation

I haven't seen anything here or on MDN. I'm sure I'm just missing something. There's got to be some documentation on this somewhere.

Functionally, it looks like it allows you to nest a variable inside a string without doing concatenation using the `+` operator. I'm looking for documentation on this feature.

Example:

```js
var string = 'this is a string';

console.log(`Insert a string here: ${string}`);
```

Comment: [ECMAScript 2015 template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: This isn't a bad question. It's a new feature, and I sure can't find a duplicate on SO, though an example of what exactly was seen would've been good.

Comment: @squint—agree, but sample code and reference to the source would have been helpful.

Comment: Example added. Reference was in a coding challenge but it was a given, as if it was something you just use. Hadn't seen anything on it and couldn't find anything either. 
(Over the last several years I've never had to ask a Q here. SO just seems to have almost everything now...)

Answer (score 285, accepted):

You're talking about [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), which use backquotes (`), as opposed to conventional quotation marks.

They allow for both multiline strings and string interpolation.

Multiline strings:

```js
console.log(`foo
bar`);
// foo
// bar
```

String interpolation:

```js
var foo = 'bar';
console.log(`Let's meet at the ${foo}`);
// Let's meet at the bar
```

Comment: Cool: You can even "inject" code: `console.log(\`Your array:\n ${arr.join('\n ')}\`)`

Comment: Seems to be an alternative to string concatenation console.log("Let's meet at the "+foo);

Answer (score 27):

You can have expressions within the template strings/literals. Example:

```js
const one = 1;
const two = 2;
const result = `One add two is ${one + two}`;
console.log(result); // output: One add two is 3
```

Comment: Is it correct to say that template strings can be used to inject code into the string?

Comment: You're injecting expressions and expressions are code. You can't inject any type of code, however, only JavaScript expressions.

Comment: I will try to be more specific. When using string literals I can inject expressions like _obj.value_ INSIDE any string using the ${ } notation. Right?

Comment: Yes, and you can try it out for yourself in the console, e.g. `hey ${obj.name}`

Answer (score 11):

You can also perform Implicit Type Conversions with template literals.
Example:

```
let fruits = ["mango","orange","pineapple","papaya"];

console.log(`My favourite fruits are ${fruits}`);
// My favourite fruits are mango,orange,pineapple,papaya
```

Answer (score 2):

It's used to reference a variable within string:

```
let someVar = "World!"
console.log(`Hello ${someVar}`); // Output is Hello World!
```

Comment: Not just _any_ string, though. Only [_template strings_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). That's an important distinction.

Answer (score 0):

Input:

```
const firstName = 'Sachin';
const age = 16
alert(`${firstName} is ${age} years old`)
```

Output:

```
Sachin is 16 years old
```

Comment: You missed some semicolons, please be careful.