# What is the name of the ${} notation in Angular2 (TypeScript)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have seen the following syntax used in an [Angular2 tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4M-VzJq4XIk)

`(click)="choose('${RED}')"`

which references

`export const RED = '#1976d2';`

I have not seen this syntax in the documentation and I'm not sure how to look it up. Is it deprecated?

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/q/35835362/3001761, both explain that these are template strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not Angular2 related, it's pure TypeScript string interpolation or [Template Strings](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/template-strings.html), and it only works in `.ts` files, but not in `.html` files when you have the template content in a different file than the component class.

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings