# Can anyone help me with ${}?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with using ${'variable'+i} in a loop function. My task is to call each function from a loop. I read about template literal but I can't find anything regarding to my problem.

I would like to use

```
${'variable'+i} // (it works in php but not in javascript)
```

I have tried to use this ` but it didn't work too.

Here is my code:

```
        var call = new XMLHttpRequest();
call.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        var jumlah = myObj.jumlah;
        var varray = new Array();
        for(i=1; i<=jumlah; i++){
            varray.push(`${"myObj.namagame"+i}`);                       
        }
    }
}
    call.open("GET","'.$GLOBALS['dirfile'].'/core/update.php?f=search&q="+str,true);
    call.send();
```

Here is my JSON result

```
{"jumlah":3,"namagame1":"ark survival evolved","namagame2":"agents of mayhem","namagame3":"age of mythology"}
```

So then, I would like to get myObj.namagame1,myObj.namagame2,myObj.namagame3 that is why I use a loop function to get them then write them to the document.

Would you please to help me, I am sorry if my question is such a dumb one. Thank you

Comment: what you have tried, try posting your code.

Comment: [Check how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have posted my code, would you please to check it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does ${} (dollar sign and curly braces) mean in a string in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835362/what-does-dollar-sign-and-curly-braces-mean-in-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: I would like to use template literals in javascript. I read it from a website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using template literals in JavaScript as per my understanding. Please try following changes in your code. Hope it will work.

1. use `myObj[`namagame${i}`]` instead of `${"myObj.namagame"+i}`

With Template String Literals:

```
call.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                var jumlah = myObj.jumlah;
                var varray = new Array();
                for(i=1; i<=jumlah; i++){
              varray.push(myObj[`namagame${i}`]);                        
                }
            }
        }
```

If we want to try with out template string literal you can go with following code.

```
call.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                var jumlah = myObj.jumlah;
                var varray = new Array();
                for(i=1; i<=jumlah; i++){
              varray.push(myObj["namagame"+i]);                        
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried your code but the result is NaN

Comment: If possible can you please share your response json format. So that i can easily understand where it is going wrong.

Comment: added. Please check it.

Comment: Please try the edited answer

Comment: Still editing the answer

Comment: it didn't work, the result is "ark survival evolved1,ark survival evolved2,ark survival evolved3. Why did you indicate namagame1+i? I would like to get namagame1,namagame2,namagame3 variable from a loop function.

Comment: yaya iam editing answer. Please give me some time.

Comment: you can try either of the two codes in my answer. Please find the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the documentation on [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

> Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions. You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with them

For example:

```js
var myVar = 123;

var string = `The value of myVar is ${myVar}`;
var string2 = "The value of myVar is " + myVar;

// both of our new strings are identical

console.log(string);
console.log(string2);
```

In your example you want something like this:

```
for(i = 1; i <= jumlah; i++){
     varray.push(myObj[`namagame${i}`]);                       
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but the result is undefined1,undefined2,undefined3

Comment: What are the contents of `myObj.namagame`? This indicates your object isn't what you're expecting it to be

Comment: I obtain it from JSON, I update my post. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I've updated my answer