# Date object at the beginning of an SQL query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I am looking at another person's SQL query, and they create the following object prior to the actual query:

```
@echo ${asOfDate||2017-08-04||Date||where noshow}$ ;
```

I have tried looking into the ${}$ notation, but with no results. What does this line do?

EDIT:
Here is the original query:

```
SELECT
    ID1 ,
    ID2 ,
    SUM(The_var) AS The_var
FROM
    DB1
WHERE
    postingdate >= ${asOfDate||2017-07-01||Date||where noshow}$
GROUP BY
    1,2;
```

Comment: What program do you use to open the file?  It does not look like SQL.

Comment: This doesn't look like `tsql` - what is the full query & DBMS?

Comment: This definitely won't execute in SSMS. I'm sure it's not `tsql`. In `tsql`, `@echo` is a variable local to the query, and must be declared. It's not a command. The dollar-sign braces part looks more like [Javascript template literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835362/what-does-dollar-sign-and-curly-braces-mean-in-a-string-in-javascript).

Comment: I was under the impression that it was TSQL, but I could definitely be mistaken. I am using DB Visualizer to run the query. The portion of the query that uses this object is as follows:


SELECT
    ID1 ,
    ID2 ,
    SUM(The_var) AS The_var
FROM
    DB1
WHERE
    postingdate >= ${asOfDate||2017-07-01||Date||where noshow}$
GROUP BY
    1,2 )

Comment: Googling says thats a syntax/feature specific to dbvisualizer: http://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG10/Using+DbVisualizer+Variables

Comment: Thanks! What was your google search? I don't know how I didn't encounter this.

Comment: Was the 5th hit for *DBVisualizer "@echo"*

Comment: `@echo` is a batch file command. But the batch file could be automating sql code for execution by another tool (like dbvisualizer) that would understand the `${ ... }$` syntax.

Comment: @AlexK. you should promote that to an answer.