# Can someone explain what is meant by `${variable}%` in javascript/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a bit of a beginner still and keep coming across this in code:

`${Math.round(newProps.percent)}%` surrounded by backticks

or

`${currentBillingStartDate}` surrounded by backticks and not using the percent.

I'd like to understand when it should be used and why.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: See: [What does ${} mean in a string in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35835362/652669)

Answer (score 1):

The percent sign is just a character that is meant to be interpolated with the expression inside the `${variable}`. The result would be a string that looks like `"55%"`