# How do I concatenate two strings in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to concatenate two string in angular 7.

the function is:

```
getEmployment(id: number): Observable<Employment> {
    const url = '${this.EmploymentUrl}/${id}';
    return this.http.get<Employment>(url).pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log('fetched employment id=${id}')),
      catchError(this.handleError<Employment>('getEmployment id=${id}'))
    );
  }
```

However, when I inspect element in my web browser it shows that {id} is not found.

If I replace the second line with the following it works just fine.

```
const url = this.EmploymentUrl + '/' + id;
```

After a lot of googling I can't figure out why the first method doesn't work. Why doesn't it work and what is the difference between the two methods?

Comment: are you using backticks ? From the code it seems like you are using quote.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does ${} (dollar sign and curly braces) mean in a string in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835362/what-does-dollar-sign-and-curly-braces-mean-in-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: For template literals to work (`${id}`), you need to use backticks (`\``) instead of single quotes (`'`)

Comment: @gunjit oh wow that solved it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `` instead of quotes. more info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```
getEmployment(id: number): Observable<Employment> {
        const url = `${this.EmploymentUrl}/${id}`;
        return this.http.get<Employment>(url).pipe(
          tap(_ => this.log(`fetched employment id=${id}`)),
          catchError(this.handleError<Employment>(`getEmployment id=${id}`))
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Beacuase you are using quote (') instead backtick (`)

```js
getEmployment(id: number): Observable<Employment> {
    const url = `${this.EmploymentUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<Employment>(url).pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log('fetched employment id=${id}')),
      catchError(this.handleError<Employment>('getEmployment id=${id}'))
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simply that I have to use backpacks (`) instead of single quotes (')

Like so:

```
 const url = `${this.EmploymentUrl}/${id}`;
```

Comment: backpacks or backticks? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just do a simple string concat like

```
const url:string = this.Employment+'/'+id; // id will be converted into a string
```