# What is this syntax `${k}` in vuejs's property?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

For example:

```
<v-checkbox v-for="(v,k) in questionContent.choices" :key="k"
    v-model="answerData[question.id]" @change="saveAnswer(qe.id, question.id)"
    :label="`${k}. ${v}`"
    :value="k"
    hide-details
/>
```

What is the name of this **`${k}. ${v}`** feature ?

Comment: It isn't a Vue feature, it's core JavaScript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does ${} (dollar sign and curly braces) mean in a string in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835362/what-does-dollar-sign-and-curly-braces-mean-in-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just binds a string to the label attribute. In es6 instead of `k + ". " + v` you can do `${k}. ${v}` to concatenate a string. In order to use the "feature", called [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), the string must be in backticks instead of single or double quotes.

Some of the advantages of using template literals:

- Makes it easier to use multiline strings
- Makes it possible to use "nested templates" eg.

```js
const classes = `header ${
  isLargeScreen() ? "" : `icon-${item.isCollapsed ? "expander" : "collapser"}`
}`;
```

intead of doing something like:

```js
let classes = "header";
classes += isLargeScreen()
  ? ""
  : item.isCollapsed
  ? " icon-expander"
  : " icon-collapser";
```

*example from Mozilla. There are also more advantages listed there*

Comment: And, the feature's name is `template literal`.

Comment: Can you tell me what the advantage is? It seems like you need more symbols to concatenate this way.