# Replace function usage

Tags: typescript, function, func

Can someone explain this comment which I have received for me? Thank you.

```
 const path = this.basePath + '/configurations/${id}/LicensePackageInfo'.replace('${' + 'id' + '}', String(id));
```

const path = this.basePath + /configurations/${id}/LicensePackageInfo ;
should be fine. Dont use replace Func, the above code is using ` character to replace "replace " function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does ${} (dollar sign and curly braces) mean in a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835362/what-does-dollar-sign-and-curly-braces-mean-in-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Just use ` instead of ', you don't need to replace anything..

Answer (score 0):

the replace function takes a substring and replaces each match in a string with it.
You do not need to replace anything, the URL is correctly formatted as it is.

```
const path = this.basePath + `/configurations/${id}/LicensePackageInfo`
```

works due to a concept called string interpolation.

In JavaScript, you can put variables values inside strings created with backticks ` wrapping them in the syntax `${}` you tried to replace.

```
const basePath = 'https://google.com'
const id = 10
const path = basePath + `/configurations/${id}/LicensePackageInfo`

console.log(path) // https://google.com/configurations/10/LicensePackageInfo
```

`String interpolation example`

```
const id = 10;
console.log(`my id is: ${id}`) //my id is: 10
console.log("my id is: ${id}") //my id is: ${id}
```

To read more on the concept https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals